# Static Fields + Autowiring in Spring

Tags: spring, autowired

Can we autowire static fields in spring controller ?

eg:

```
@Autowired
    public static JNDIEMailSender jNDIEmailSender;
```

Comment: If you use global state (static variables) along with Spring - something must be wrong with your design

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, I don't think that will work.  You can add a setter method, annotate it with @Autowired and set the static field in the setter.

```
@Autowired
void setJNDIEmailSender(JNDIEmailSender jndiEmailSender) {
  ClassName.jNDIEmailSender = jndiEmailSender
}
```

Comment: agree with Denis...it was a bad design..since all classes are singleton....so no need for static classes/methods...

Comment: making classes singleton or not depend on your choice, so it is not good to generalize.

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesnt autowire static fields