# Spring MVC can't autowire collection?

Tags: java, spring

My xml looks like this:

```
<bean name="subscriberStore" class="java.util.HashSet" scope="singleton"/>
```

And I have the following code:

```
@Value("#{subscriberStore}")
private static HashSet<Subscriber> subscriberStore;
```

However, later in the above class, when I call methods on subscriberStore I get a null pointer exception. I've tried using `@Autowired` and `@Resource` in place of `@Value ..` above but it makes no difference.

Anyone have any ideas why the subscriber store is not getting initialized?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the class in which you're using the @Autowired annotation etc being loaded by Spring, or by you?  If it's not being loaded by Spring, then no dependency injection will take place fwir.

Comment: Many duplicates, including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657168/static-fields-autowiring-in-spring http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018797/autowired-static-field-spring-2-5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253694/spring-how-to-inject-a-value-to-static-field and especially http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763279/injecting-values-for-static-constants-in-spring

Comment: @skaffman My question wasn't about autowiring statics, it was about autowiring a collection, which just happens to be a static. In this case I though the problem was with it being a collection - not a static, as per my question title.

Comment: @Rory: The reason it doesn't work is because it's static, not because it's a collection. Failure to autowire collections resilts in an exception, whereas failure to autowire statics results in a null.

Comment: You could also try this trick: http://www.connorgarvey.com/blog/?p=105

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot `@Autowire` static fields.  Consider removing the `static` modifier, if possible.

Comment: Thanks this worked - I suppose the static modifier is not strictly needed anyway, since subscriberStore is a Spring singleton, is this correct?

Comment: Sure...but just because it is a Spring singleton, doesn't mean that ***YOU*** cannot create an instance using the `new` operator...