# calling non static method from static class in java with spring autowiring?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have below interface and its implementation class.

### Demo.java

```
public interface Demo{

 void showDemo();

}
```

### DemoImpl.java

```
@Service
public class DemoImpl implements Demo{

  public void showDemo(){

       //To Do

    }

}
```

Now i have one class with static method which will internally call `showDemo()` as below.

### DemoStatic.java

```
@Component
public class DemoStatic{

 @Autowired
 private Demo demo;



     public static void callShowDemo(){

       demo.showDemo(); //calling non static method from static method

       }

}
```

Here i am calling non static method from static method. Is my design correct? Or do i need to change my design? Please suggest me.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't call non static method form static method. It will not compile.

Comment: Well, you can, but you have to specify which object to call the non-static method *on*.

Comment: In this case, the method call is actually OK; the problem is the reference to the non-static variable `demo`.  There can be multiple instances of `DemoStatic`, each with its own `demo` variable.

Comment: You can just inject the bean and call `showDemo()` where you need it, no need for static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No your design is not correct.

```
private Demo demo;
```

has to be

```
private static Demo demo;
```

You just cant use NON static members in a static method

Comment: Doltan, if i make Demo variable static then will be there be any issues? Thanks!

Comment: no there wont be an issue. But the element is then static and you should know what static means.

Comment: The statement should be "You just cant use NON static members in a static method"

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way

```
@Component
public class DemoStatic {

 private static Demo demo;

 @Autowired
 public void setDemo(Demo d) {
     demo = d;
 }

  public static void callShowDemo(){
       demo.showDemo(); //calling static method from static method
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code will not compile at all. You are trying to refer non-static reference from static method, which is not allowed in Java.

Refer this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972764/non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static-context) link for better understanding.

Make the following change:

```
public static Demo demo;
```

Comment: Can Spring autowire static fields?!

Comment: @SilviuBurcea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657168/static-fields-autowiring-in-spring

Comment: @SilviuBurcea : I do not have much expertise in Springs, so cannot comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

when you call DemoStatic.callShowDemo()，the demo may not been instand