# @Autowired bean is coming as null at static method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, static, autowired

i have two class name with Bean class and Util class. At Util class i want to call the method from Bean Class. But the thing is when i @Autowired the Bean class at Util class. There is null pointer exception because of static method at Util class. Here is my code.

```
public class Util{

@Autowired
private static BaseServiceCommonPropertiesBean baseServiceCommonPropertiesBean;

private static String PASSPHRASE = baseServiceCommonPropertiesBean.getBassURL();
System.out.print(PASSPHRASE);

}
```

Here is for BaseServiceCommonPropertiesBean class

```
public class BaseServiceCommonPropertiesBean {

@Value("#{baseServiceapplicationProperties['mobi.sc.travellers.amr.email.base.url']}")
    private String baseUrl;

public String getBaseUrl(){
        return baseUrl;
    }

}
```

Whenever the system read the baseServiceCommonPropertiesBean.getPassPhrase() method. It goes out and stop working . I tried @Postconstruct annotation before it does not work. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you cannot use @Autowired on static fields.   What do you mean "@Postconstruct annotation before it does not work" ?   (it most certainly does behave according to it's documentation) - can you edit the question to show us your attempt?   More to the point, WHY do you want PASSPHRASE set statically - ie, why is a `getPassphrase()` method on the instance is not sufficient?

Comment: One of the benefits of spring is not having to use static fields.

Comment: Either getPassphrase() or all of the get method from BaseServiceCommonPropertiesBean cannot used.  and for PostConstruct i used below code before it does not work also. still come as null pointer exception. Thanks.

`
@Component
public class Util{

  private static BaseServiceCommonPropertiesBean baseServiceCommonPropertiesBean;

  @Autowired
  private BaseServiceCommonPropertiesBean bean;

  @PostConstruct     
  private void initStaticBean () {
     baseServiceCommonPropertiesBean = this.bean;
  }

}
`

Comment: Don't use `static`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946852/calling-non-static-method-from-static-class-in-java-with-spring-autowiring

Answer (score 1):

You cannot @Autowired static fields, either remove static from BaseServiceCommonPropertiesBean or rewrite your Util to be something like below:

```
@Component
public class Util{

private static BaseServiceCommonPropertiesBean baseServiceCommonPropertiesBean;

@Autowired
    public void setBaseServiceCommonPropertiesBean(BaseServiceCommonPropertiesBean baseServiceCommonPropertiesBean){
        Util.baseServiceCommonPropertiesBean = baseServiceCommonPropertiesBean;
    }

private static String PASSPHRASE = baseServiceCommonPropertiesBean.getBassURL();
System.out.print(PASSPHRASE);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried the way you mention. But still having error and nothing coming out @3_eyed_raven.

Comment: how exactly should it work, if Util is not scanned for creation and autowiring by spring?  To my knowledge you cannot simply put @Autowired and call it a day

Comment: @KaungKhantZaw - I haven't tried it myself, the answer is a general guidance, try adding @ Component to Util class. Also, why not use non-static Util?